# Congruence induction step: $2*7^n\equiv 2^n(2+5n)(\mod25)$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, induction

I am trying to proof by induction: 
$2*7^n\equiv 2^n(2+5n)(\mod25)$

However I can't proof the induction step:
$2*7^{(n+1)}\equiv 2^{(n+1)}(2+5(n+1))(\mod25)$

This is what I got so far:
 $2*7^{(n+1)} = \\ 2*7^n*7 = (base) \\ 2*7*2^n(2+5n) = \\ 7*2^{(n+1)}(2+5n) = \\7*(2^{(n+2)}+2^{(n+1)}5n) = \\2^{(n+2)}(5+2)+2^{(n+1)}35n \equiv  \\2^{(n+2)}5+2^{(n+3)}+2^{(n+1)}10n  = \\ 2^{(n+2)}5+2^{(n+3)}+2^{(n+2)}5n = \\ 2^{(n+2)}(2+ 5(n+1)) (\mod 25)  $  
 **but:** $\neq2^{(n+1)}(2+5(n+1))(\mod25) $

I feel like I'm missing something obvious...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the second line of the induction step, it should be $$2*7^n * 7 \equiv 7*2^n(2+5n),$$ hence the extra multiple of $2$ at your last step.

Comment: Ah, of course. Obvious indeed... Thanks alot!